# visual studio express 2012 simple c program fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012

While compiling and linking the following simple test.c using: cl.exe test.c in windows 7 console:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    int i;
    i=0;
    printf("i=%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

I got LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined. It compiles without problem, but failed in linking. Also if I change the filename to test.cpp then it works fine. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and compiled it with `cl.exe test.c` and it worked fine. I think you have a configuration problem.

First off, are you using the Visual Studio command line environment? Ensure that by typing on a command line:

```
vsvars32
```

Then try using:

```
cl.exe test.c kernel32.lib
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your suggestion but it did not work. I'm using VS 2012 Express. Again there is no problem with CPP files, it's just the C files that couldn't be linked.